# Data not being inserted into GridDB container

Tags: python, database, griddb

I'm trying to insert some data into a GridDB container using the Python API, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

```py
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
store = factory.get_store(
    host='localhost',
    port=2406,
    cluster_name='mycluster',
    username='admin',
    password='admin'
)

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("mycontainer",
                               [["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                                ["name", griddb.Type.STRING]],
                               griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)

con = store.get_container(conInfo)
con.put([1, "John"])
con.put([2, "Jane"])
```

When I run this code, it doesn't raise any errors, but when I try to query the container, it's empty. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to look on the internet for a solution, but it seems nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be causing the issue is that you haven't called `con.create()` after creating the container. The `create()` method initializes the container, which is necessary before you can insert data into it.

Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
store = factory.get_store(
    host='localhost',
    port=2406,
    cluster_name='mycluster',
    username='admin',
    password='admin'
)

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("mycontainer",
                               [["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                                ["name", griddb.Type.STRING]],
                               griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)

con = store.get_container(conInfo)
con.create() # Initialize the container
con.put([1, "John"])
con.put([2, "Jane"])
```