# Error while installing griddb_python library

Tags: griddb

I am trying to install griddb_python python library on jupyter notebook and I got this error message.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fab172lb\\griddb-python_28bc1887464144bba98ec07fc3ec5a3f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fab172lb\\griddb-python_28bc1887464144bba98ec07fc3ec5a3f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-suyu5koa\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Include\griddb-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Has any had similar issue and how did you resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look correct. You'd have to also supply what you ran to cause that to show up? Anyways if you want to install things, ideally you open Jupyter and use `%conda install ...`, where ... is the rest of the command needed, since you have chosen the Anaconda Distribution as your primary package manager by installing that. That is in the typical situation. However, I'm not seeing griddb having a conda recipe, and so you can resort to using `%pip install`. So open the notebook where you plan to import griddb and run `%pip install gridbp_python` based on ...

Comment: <continued>  [here](https://pypi.org/project/griddb-python/). Then after that install runs to completion, restart the kernel and run `import griddb_python as griddb`. If that runs in the notebook then it is installed and imported into the namespace ready to use. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133931/8508004) for more example code like that. The guide for installation I used is like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78151136/8508004) transposed to 'griddb_python`. Read that answer for more about what is happening.